# Android Facebook Graph API JSON returns no email

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, eclipse-adt

I'm currently having some issues trying to obtain the user's email via GraphUser api object.

I managed to obtain  firstname, lastname and everything else but **not the email**.

I've done my research that you'll need to add some permission to obtain user's email (login email to facebook, not xxx@facebook.com). I'm stuck! How do I do this in Android?

```
private class FacebookloginDelegateImpl extends FacebookloginDelegate
{
    /*
     * Optional callback method
     */ 
    protected void onCompletedProgress(GraphUser user,
            Response response) 
    {
        Log.d("FB UserID:", user.getId());
        Log.d("FB FirstName:", user.getFirstName());
        Log.d("FB LastName:", user.getLastName());
        Log.d("Object:", user.toString());
        Log.d("Response:", response.toString());
        //Log.d("FB Email:", (String) user.asMap().get("email"));

        String userID = user.getId();
        String firstname = user.getFirstName();
        String lastname = user.getLastName();
        String email= "";
        try {
            email = user.getInnerJSONObject().getString("email");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("FB Email:", email);

        LoginActivity.this.requestFacebookLogin(userID, firstname, lastname);

        //String stringData = "{\"ID\":\""+user.getId()+"\",\"Name\":\""+user.getName()+"\"}";  
    }
```

Comment: did you get this in the end? I have the same problem,

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the user has set up another email than the default facebook one? Facebook forces everyone to have their email and you need to go in and change it in order to have another one.

Comment: I actually created a new facebook account for this purpose. I need the login email for facebook (e.g marcus@gmail.com), not the default facebook email.

Comment: @user2571000 have you made sure that the login email is set up as the ACTUAL Email? Login email is just a name to facebook, you can use aliases as login as well.